# Ruby: A function returning another function

Tags: ruby, function

In order to understand the functional programming part of ruby I want to write a function that takes 2 functions f(x,y),g(x) as arguments and returns a new function h(x,y)=f(g(x),g(y)).

```
def foo(x, y)
    return x+y
end

def bar(x)
    return 2*x
end

def comp(f,g)

end

f=comp(f,g)
f(1,2) #=> 6
```

I tried things like

```
def comp(f,g)
    mylambda = lambda {|x,y| return f(g(x),g(y))}
    return mylambda
end
f=comp(foo, bar)
f.call(1,2)
```

I thought f would be a Proc now, and I could just call it. But apparently "in `foo': wrong number of arguments (0 for 2) (ArgumentError)"

What syntax would I have to use? And is it possible to return a "real" function instead of a Proc, so that instead of f.call(1,2) I could just writhe f(1,2) like if I had just defined f myself normaly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This type of functional pattern doesn't work as smoothly as on more functional languages, as javascript or python. Since ruby has optional parentheses, writing `foo` is the same as calling the `foo` method without passing any arguments.

To get a reference to a method, you need to use the `Object#method` method:

```
def foo(x, y)
  x + y
end

def bar(x)
  x * 2
end

def comp(f, g)
  lambda { |x, y| f.call(g.call(x), g.call(y)) }
end

h = comp(method(:foo), method(:bar))
h.call(1, 2) # => 6
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
def foo() lambda {|x,y| x+y} end
def bar() lambda {|x| 2*x} end
def comp(f,g) lambda {|x,y| f[g[x], g[y]]} end
h = comp(foo, bar)
h[1,2]       # => 6
```

or any of the following

```
h.call(1,2)  # => 6
h.(1,2)      # => 6
h.yield(1,2) # => 6
```

If you'd prefer,

```
foo = lambda {|x,y| x+y}
bar = lambda {|x| 2*x}
```

Before this question I was unaware of the myriad of ways one can now invoke a lambda (or proc). (The rationale for providing `Proc#yield` escapes me, as it is the same as `call` and may be confused with the unrelated `yield` keyword we all know and love.) One could substitute `Proc.new` or `proc` for `lambda`, or create the lambda with the "stabby" syntax `->` (e.g., `def bar() ->(x) {2*x} end`.

Answer (score 2):

Ruby doesn't have first class functions like Python. Ruby has lambdas, and method objects that can be constructed specially from a method, but methods themselves are *not* objects. The closest you'll get to this is this:

```
def foo(x, y)
    return x+y
end

def bar(x)
    return 2*x
end

def comp(f,g)
  return lambda {|x, y| f.call(g.call(x), g.call(y))}
end

f=comp(method(:f),method(:g))
f.call(1,2) #=> 6
```

Also, for the calling syntax point, you can call a lambda with square brackets, so you could do this:

```
f[1,2]
```

Comment: @Denis: Not really. There is an object that can *represent* methods after calling a special constructor, but the method itself, the name of the method does *not* refer to an object. This is what I mean by "Ruby does not have first class functions".

Comment: You evidently have a stylistic preference for explicit `return`'s.  Any particular reasons (if not just muscle-memory from years of C/C++)?

Comment: @CarySwoveland: I've been doing a lot of Objective C lately. Things get into your habits :).

Answer (score 2):

What you have there aren't functions, they are methods. Functions (more precisely: procedures) are defined like this:

```
foo = -> (x, y) { x + y }

bar = -> x { 2 * x }

comp = -> (f, g) { -> (x, y) { f.(g.(x), g.(y)) } }

f = comp.(foo, bar)

f.(1, 2) #=> 6
```

Answer (score 0):

```
f=comp(foo, bar)
```

This won't work like it would in python. The error message you're getting is wanting to see something like this.

```
f = comp(foo(1,2), bar(1))
```

You need to actually make `foo` and `bar` lambdas themselves (or methods that return lambdas) if you want to call it like that:

```
foo = lambda { |x, y| x + y }
bar = lambda { |x| 2 * x }

or

def foo(x, y)
  lambda { |x, y| x + y}
end

def bar(x)
  lambda { |x| 2 * x }
end
```

Then you can achieve what you want to do.